# How can I search a json file to return values satisfying a particular criteria?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, anaconda

Here is my json file:

```
{"items":[{"reputation":6623,"user_id":836,"location":"Durham, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater","display_name":"Neil Slater"},{"reputation":6267,"user_id":381,"location":"Silicon Valley","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre","display_name":"Emre"},{"reputation":5033,"user_id":2452,"location":"Atlanta, GA","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/2452/aleksandr-blekh","display_name":"Aleksandr Blekh"},{"reputation":3537,"user_id":11097,"location":"Gurgaon, India","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097/dawny33","display_name":"Dawny33"},{"reputation":3257,"user_id":21,"location":"London, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/21/sean-owen","display_name":"Sean Owen"}]
```

How can I extract display names of users who are from a particular location, say Israel? I am trying to write nested query for the same but getting syntax errors.

Comment: This is a bit broad as it is. Please include the code you're getting syntax errors from in the question.

Comment: what do you mean by nested query?

Comment: I imagine he means a multi-level dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

fp = open('myfile.json', 'r')
data = json.load(fp)

for user in data['items']:
    if user['location'] == 'Israel':
        print (user['display_name'])
```

Comment: I am getting this error : KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-8c606782ce7a> in <module>()
      1 for user in data4['items']:
----> 2     if user['location']=='Israel':
      3         print(user['display_name'])

KeyError: 'location'

Comment: What do you see if you `print (user)` as the first line in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using this approach:

```
   data = {"items":[{"reputation":6623,"user_id":836,"location":"Durham, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater","display_name":"Neil Slater"},{"reputation":6267,"user_id":381,"location":"Silicon Valley","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre","display_name":"Emre"},{"reputation":5033,"user_id":2452,"location":"Atlanta, GA","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/2452/aleksandr-blekh","display_name":"Aleksandr Blekh"},{"reputation":3537,"user_id":11097,"location":"Gurgaon, India","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097/dawny33","display_name":"Dawny33"},{"reputation":3257,"user_id":21,"location":"London, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/21/sean-owen","display_name":"Sean Owen"}]}


    for key,value in data.items():
             for i in range(len(value)):
                     if 'United Kingdom' in value[i]['location']:
                             print value[i]['display_name']
```

Output:

```
Neil Slater
Sean Owen
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code :

```
import json

location = 'United Kingdom'
jso = '''{"items":[{"reputation":6623,"user_id":836,"location":"Durham, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/836/neil-slater","display_name":"Neil Slater"},{"reputation":6267,"user_id":381,"location":"Silicon Valley","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/381/emre","display_name":"Emre"},{"reputation":5033,"user_id":2452,"location":"Atlanta, GA","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/2452/aleksandr-blekh","display_name":"Aleksandr Blekh"},{"reputation":3537,"user_id":11097,"location":"Gurgaon, India","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/11097/dawny33","display_name":"Dawny33"},{"reputation":3257,"user_id":21,"location":"London, United Kingdom","link":"https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/21/sean-owen","display_name":"Sean Owen"}]}'''

dic = json.loads(jso)

for entry in dic['items']:
    if location.lower() in entry['location'].lower():
        print (entry['display_name'])
```

Output:

```
Neil Slater
Sean Owen
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a list comprehension like this:

```
import json
jsd = json.loads(<JSON STRING>) #  This return a dict object
displayNamesList = [dn['display_name'] for dn in jsd.values()[0] if 'Israel' in dn['display_name']]
```

But the most important it's that you need to review a well formed json struct. I use http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer in order to validate a json struct.

Hope this help you.